# Changing method execution in runtime (Java)

Tags: java

I am a Software Engineer in Test, and I am trying to write code that can replace production side method so that test can execute those instead. Basically, I do not want to modify production code for testability.

Here is a simple scenario:

```
public class Foo {

     public static void foo() {
         printA();
     }

     public static void printA() {
         System.out.println("A");
     }

     public static void printB() {
         System.out.println("B");
     }
}

public class Foobar {

    public Foobar() {

    }

    public void test() {
        Foo.foo();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Try changing the method here

        new Foobar().test();
    }

}
```

As you can see, when the main executes, it will print "A" since it calls the method printA on static method foo(). Now on runtime, is there a way I can inject or modify such that foo will call printB instead of printA?

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: You can use [Instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) to acquire access to class bytes, and then use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/), or another bytecode analysis/modification library to modify the method.

Comment: I managed to do something like that once using [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).

It provides `advices`, which can be used to execute some code *around* a method (before and after its execution), including bypassing the call to original method altogether and returning some arbirary value

Answer (score 0):

If you're just doing this for testing out classes, you could use a mocking framework to mock the classes on the server.  I like [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it yourself using the java reflection api, or you can you use a tool like [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/).

Comment: I don't believe reflections allow code swapping. Can you elaborate?